# Why is my arraylist only filled with one element?

Tags: java, arraylist

When printing out f(i).x in the code, the right x values are shown. But when I try to get as example: points.get(2).x or any other value, I always get the same x value. Any help would be awesome.

Main Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (float i = -5; i <= 5; i+=0.1) {
            points.add(f(i));

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(points.get(i).x);
            // shows always the same number: 4.95...
        }

    }

    public static Point f(float x) {
        return new Point(x, (-0.15f*((x + -2.1f) * (x + -2.1f)) + 4.3f));
    }
}
```

Point Class:

```
public class Point {

    public static float x;
    public static float y;

    public Point(float x_, float y_) {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are the fields in Point static? Is that a typo?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, no it's not a typo. This is exactly THE reason why it doesn't work

Comment: @igorepst Typo was slightly the wrong word. That's why it's not working, but it could have been a simple mistake by the OP to include `static`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't think static would have any effect on this.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how they got there ^^.

Comment: @SamOrozco Yes it does. Everytime they create a new object in `f`, they overwrite the static field. When they iterate over the points and print `x`, it'll reference the static field and always print the same thing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate My bad, I thought you meant the static ArrayList<>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you defined `x` and `y` in your `Point` class as static, this is what caused all the points to have the very same values. [Please read about static variables](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-class-block-methods-variables/)

> Static members belong to the class instead of a specific instance,
>   this means if you make a member static, you can access it without
>   object